# unable to login with Facebook in my app, page turn white no action further

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-app-requests

My app have rejected being of this problem two times.

Some times (very rarely), Testers are unable to login with Facebook. Please see the attached screenshot/s for more information.

The steps to reproduce are(produce some time very rarely):

1. Launch the app
2. Tap Facebook
3. Login with Facebook credentials
4. Page turns white and no further action occurs

[image: They said nothing is happening after this image]
Please help me regard this. Thanks

Comment: Show the code you've tried so far so you can get more specific advice.

Comment: Thanks! @SurajSukale  for quick reply. My tester never faced this problem. i was using latest idk of Facebook. i uploaded it again on iTunes yesterday. now its approved by apple and available on App Store. :)

Comment: Ok.. congratulations

Answer (score 0):

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
          openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
       annotation:(id)annotation
  {
      return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance]application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];

}

Comment: I think you haven't implemented this delegate method in your appdelegate.m class file.

Comment: Thanks! @Xcoder  for quick reply. I have already implemented this delegate. My tester never faced this problem. i was using latest idk of Facebook. i uploaded it again on iTunes yesterday. now its approved by apple and available on App Store. :)